# Work Gives Professional Experience, School Gives ___ Experience?

Tags: vocabulary

If I'm trying to differentiate between my knowledge base, how do I address the experience gained in school? For example,

"My professional experience includes C#, .NET, etc."

"My *educational?* experience includes Java, C++, etc."

Comment: In theory, school gives *scholastic* training, not experience. It could give experience, but most entities wouldn't consider book knowledge and test taking to be "experience". There is what you learn (training), what you know (knowledge), and what you've actually done with the first two outside of school (experience).

Comment: I agree with SrJoven. How about "curricular exposure to Java... etc."?

Comment: Actually, school should provide training or education, or both, depending on the type of school. And *scholastic* just means related to school or schooling.  Of course school provides students with the experience of school: yes, it provides scholastic experience (though that is not its aim).

Answer (score 2):

The term *[academic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/academic)* means

> Of or relating to education and scholarship:
>   *academic achievement;
>   he had no academic qualifications* [*Oxford Online Dictionary*]

In your example, *[experience](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experience)* means

> direct observation of or participation in events as a basis of knowledge [*Merriam-Webster*]

The *academic experience* could include classes taken, lectures attended, informal discussions participated in. However, when formally describing qualifications, the term *experience* is more commonly reserved to less theoretical and more practical activities.

In describing  scholarly training, the term *background* is often used. This can equally be applied to employment, including professional pursuits.