# University research or Academic research

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, terminology

What do you call researches that are carried out in the universities as thesis or...?

- academic researches
- university researches
- researches in university

Comment: Some context would help. Why are you trying to qualify or differentiate it? Quite a bit of industry research takes place at universities, and I would say quite a bit of that type of research could directly be used in some theses or dissertations.

Comment: researches could be applied, basic,... shallow, deep,..... but they are just take place in university (bound to the place). actually I want to say how university researches could contribute to the industry problems

Answer (score -1):

**Scientific research**

If your research based on scientific principles it is called Scientific research.

The complete process will actually involve everything from "Thesis" to "Peer Review".

The Wikipedia acticle on [scientific method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) sums it all up nicely.

Some more clarification or context on the question would help, since there seem to be different ways of understanding it. 
Is the focus on research that is carried out in a university or was the question about research as it is carried out in a university or in other places as Academic research suggests or about the kind of research which would be scientific research for my opinion then since Academic research does not have to take place in a university necessarily.

If you are looking for a term to describe the research at a University in general one would however phrase that differently than describing a specific research. The exact context will matter a lot for selecting the proper words then.

When referring to concrete research something like *Academic Research at xyz University* naming the field of research as well might work out best. As a caption sometimes just *Academics* will do, however is not clearly limited. Then again, depending on the field, *Scientific Research at xyz University* might sound good as well, since you mentioned the thesis. If it is used in a publication by the university, it would be worded differently, then for example on a resume.
To get a clear answer you will have to provide more information on context, purpose and/or target audience.

Comment: Scientific research can be and is conducted outside academia, and not all research conducted in academia is scientific. Also, I think you're ignoring the context of the asker's question (header in a resume), and the previous comments on it (that it might be best to use the word "training" or "study", or some equivalent).

Comment: Where do you see that context? (header in a resume) 
All I see is:
University research or Academic research
What is called the researches which are carried in the universities as thesis or ....

academic researches or university researches or researches in university?

For me that sounds like someone with maybe not perfect English skills (like myself) is asking for the right term for research like it is carried out in Universities that starts with a thesis why otherwise would he mention thesis in his question?

Comment: Sorry, I confused this question with a (very) similar question from earlier today: [Work gives professional experience, school gives ??? experience](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193088/work-gives-professional-experience-school-gives-experience). (I spend too much time on this site.)

Comment: maybe you want to give it an up vote then ;-)

Comment: Yes, My English is not perfect, I look for a term which exactly point the researches carried out in the universities (not in any other place) actually they are bound to the place

Comment: @fgwaller, Only two of my four critiques was misplaced ;). If you make your answer more precisely about (not-necessarily-scientific) conducted *only in* universities, I'll upvote it (and it looks like Ahmad is prepared to accept it).